# Spring Security allow all requests

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to develop rest application where only base auth.
I use java-base configuration and have security class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("123456").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().denyAll();
    }
}
```

also I see that security filter was added

```
[org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5601cb02, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3be5386f, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@218c240d, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@46b36d4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@d0f92f5, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@23004472, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@57a57f43, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@42b44dda, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3a81a7cd, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@53e708c7, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@66a7dab9]
```

but when I connect to my controller from browser where I have code

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
```

I have the NPE, because auth is null. But as I understand Spring Security must decline any requests to any my urls before method executions.
Can someone tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: That is the reason. I don't know why security filter allow request to method.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
```

If the problem persists I think it may be due to the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter that puts an AnonymousToken in the SecurityContextHolder. In this case you need to disable this filter `anonymous().disable()` or use a RoleVoter.

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

UPDATE: 
Just a doubt, are you sure that your app is taking your configuration from your SecurityConfig?. From Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc) you have to do this:

```
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    // ... other overrides ...
}
```

I don't know if @Configuration works in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: I've used 

public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

 @Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  ctx.register(CoreConfig.class);

in CoreConfig I've imported SecurityConfig what is above. How can I check that spring filter is added?

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe, I found mistake. I haven't add spring filter to application. By I don't know how do it with 1 class webInitializer. I've found how to add spring security with  extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer, but my application configurations were added by implementation WebInitializer. How can I join this?

Comment: AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer. Why you don't want to make your class WebInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer  instead of implement WebApplicationInitializer? In your current config try with ctx.register(SecurityConfig.class) after ctx.register(CoreConfig.class)